# Check if current page == a link

Tags: views, theming, navigation

I'm working with a content type `skills`, where i made a view with the titles(as links). This generates a kind of menu. Which is what i'm aiming for. Now i need it to check if you are on one of the pages in this so called menu. Because ofcourse. if the link is active it needs different markup.

note: I can't solve this with an `onclick` because there are multiple ways of getting on the skill pages.

I wrote the following code. but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function (themename)_preprocess_views_view_fields__our_skills(&$variables) {
    $variables['active_class'] = '';
    $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();

    foreach ($variables['fields'] as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
        if ($fieldname == "path" $$ $fieldvalue == $current_uri){
            $variables['active_class'] = ' active';
        }
    }
}
```

The code above returns `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is enough assuming that you just want the color of link to change when active,

CSS for links within said view

```
.view-name > .view-content > .view-grouping > .view-grouping-header > a { color: blue; }
```

CSS for active links

```
.view-name > .view-content > .view-grouping > .view-grouping-header > a.active { background-color: white; text-decoration: none; border-left: #95e5d4 10px solid; color: black; }
```